# Camel-Netty4 TCP not able to connect to remote server

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I'm facing problem while trying to connect remote server1 with remote server2 by using camel-netty4.

While trying to connect with remote server, throws below exception, but works for localhost.

> leTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory | 313 - org.apache.camel.camel-netty4 - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | ServerBootstrap unbinding from :
>   NettyConsumer                    | 313 - org.apache.camel.camel-netty4 - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Netty consumer unbound from: :
>   BlueprintCamelContext            | 234 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext() due Cannot assign requested address
>   java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_131]

Please advice to resolve this issue, thank you.

Comment: This is a bit hard to help. So it sounds like some networking connectivity problem between where you run this app and the remote host. Can be firewall blocking and 100s of other network things.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using some random number 5005 as port number, but for this port number there is no service running on remote server, is this cause this issue? thanks.

Comment: Consumer is listing to the sever, but producer is throwing connection exception, any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake while configuring TCP client and server, now created a consumer which is listening to same host, and a producer created to send message to remote server.